# How to define a menu for use with only certain controllers and when certain model is present ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a submenu I want to display only when certain controllers are used and a certain model is present.  I created a partial and tried to render it in the _Layout.cshtml but I get an error stating model item passed is of type ... but this dictionary requires item of type...

I could put the menu in each of my views for the controllers with the right type of model being passed but that seems like the less flexible way.

Currently I am checking if my model is null in the _submenu partial

```
@if(Model != null)
```

However, this will let any type of model through and then when it is the wrong type it errors.

I thought the best way would be to specify that my @Html.Partial is only run when certain controllers are used.  Or Is there a way to verify the model type so the code doesn't run if the model passed to the view is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need your model to be dynamic ([Check this website](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/01/28/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views.aspx) for more information on this), then on your view you can just check the type of the model and act accordingly:

```
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "IndexNotStonglyTyped";
}

<h2>Index Not Stongly Typed</h2>

<p>
@if(Model is MyType) {
   <span>got myType!</span>
}

</p>
```

Note: Original example taken from the website mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dynamic model option and the comparing type option.  This is helpful.  I will see if I can get what I need from this.

Comment: This is partially answered.  I am currently looking to see if I can use only the model and not have to check the controller it is coming from.  I could potentially have the model sent to one controller where I want the menu to display and another controller where I don't but the same model is passed.  For example.  yes/1 and no/1 but only show the menu on yes/1.  Of course I would have more controllers.  I can always put in each view but that is a pain.  I am looking for a way to say if it is this controller and this model show the menu.

Comment: @Xaxum why don't you add a property `ShowMenu` to your model? you could even have a base class with properties (like this) related to the layout and have other model classes inherit from this base class. Then put your menu in the partial view and check for these properties to render accordingly.